# Navigation-like behaviour without UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uinavigationbar

i am coding a project in which some products with their respective categories and subcategories are read from an xml file and then must be displayed in a UITableView.

Problem is, that there is no fixed depth of levels (the xml tag reads like this: Category > subcategory > subsubcategory > ... > etc) so i can't have a fixed set of views and thus to use a UINavigationController.

So at the moment - and it's working pefectly - i read the data from some NSMutableArrays i have loaded from the xml file and i am showing them in a UITableView. Working as intended. The objects even have links to eachother and so the new data set is a child of the element last pressed on the UITableView.

But, obviously, i need a back button, and this is where i got stuck, i've done it with UINavigationController before, but i can't seem to find a way to

a) add a back button to the navigation bar (I added a UINavigationBar via the IntefaceBuilder and linked it to the IBOutlet)

b) associate some code to call the previous data set when the button is pressed.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You should still follow the usual navigation controller design pattern. If you have multiple levels of categories, call the same view controller **recursively**.

I once did such an implementation (also on the basis of an xml file) where in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` I would check if the object selected has any more "children" - in which case I would push another equivalent view controller on top of the navigation stack; if not, I would present the detail view controller.

Comment: thing is, that with my current design i am only using one view controller, the one that contains the table (and the nav-bar) and i am just reloading the table's data each time the user taps an item.

Comment: I see - I still think going with multiple instances of `UITableViewController` is the better approach. (You would not have to write a new controller subclass.) In this way, you also do not have to implement your own animations etc.

Comment: since i am kinda new to ObjC and though i understand the notion, i am having a hard time figuring out how to do it, mind tossing me some dummy code on how to work around on multiple instances of UITableViewController? I mean, where in the class (which is the tableView's delegate and datasource) should i be creating them and how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I ultimately added a `UINavigationController` for the passing from the categories to the product view itself, but still all the categories are handled from one `UINavigationController` and i would like to change that to comply to your (more logical) model

Comment: Well, you made it work. How are you handling the animations from one level to the next?

Comment: Updates are handled this way:
[self.tableview beginUpdates];
[self.tableview deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[self.tableview insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
[self.tableview endUpdates];

the animation is cute, but the last part, when i actually use the pushViewController method uses the standard animation which i would like to have in all my transitions, and all in all, having multiple UITableViewControllers seems more logical. Still no idea how to do it though :(

Comment: Which part don't you understand? Just use `[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController];`. Do you need sample code?

Comment: Hello Mundi and sorry for the constant disturbing, i've managed to do it, adding new `UITableViewControllers` dynamically and setting their datasources and delegates to the class i am working in. My issue now is, how to overrid the "Back" button of the `UINavigationController` and make it update the datasource (which as you recall is dynamically constructed)

Comment: That is easy: just make a `UIBarButtonItem` and set it as `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` and the back button will be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this you have to implement a stack structure, with it's functions to push and pop. Just the same way as UINavigationController works. If your solution is not a fully customized one I would simply use UINavigationController pushing UITableViewControllers and have it handle the stack for me, as opposed to re-inventing the wheel.